# Value minus 1 for each row IF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iteration

I have very limited coding experience, and even less so with Google Apps Scripts. I already have a script with some functions in place, that i've put together from forums... the next step for me would be to make it (if possible) do -1 for each row, in a certain column (e.g. let's say my values are in column C).

Specifically:

- IF the value of this row is higher than the row above: Leave that value and skip to next row. OR
- IF the value of this = 1: Also leave that value and skip to next row.
- ELSE I would want it to do value of row above -1.

So if column C has these values:
5
5
5
5
5
3
3
3
1
2
2

The output should be
5
4
3
2
1
3
2
1
1
2
1

It could start at C3, as C1 is a header and C2 should also be left as is.. And yes, It can completely overwrite the data in this column C, because it's already a copy of column B, which I've done with this little code:

```
function copytestdata() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Output');
  sheet.getRange("B2:B").copyTo(sheet.getRange("C2:C"), {contentsOnly:true});
 }
```

Probably very easy to make if you know how to do G Apps.. Anyone that can help :)?

Comment: Your code runs just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.  I did not do all of your conditionals but I assume you will want to figure that out yourself.

```
function copytestdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Output');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  let vo = vs.map((r,i) => {
    //I just subtracted one
    if(r[0] > 1) {
      return [r[0] - 1];
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(2,3,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

COL2 was my data and COL3 is my output

| COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 16 | 15 |
| 14 | 13 |
| 16 | 15 |
| 14 | 13 |
| 12 | 11 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 17 | 16 |
| 19 | 18 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 12 | 11 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 12 | 11 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 11 | 10 |
| 7 | 6 |

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I could not figure out why it was looking so weird.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

There are two different intepretations to your description and therefore I provide two solutions so you can pick up whichever suits you the best.

After every iteration you need to check the value in the row above, but the value in the previous row could be either the **original** value (the one in column C) or the value that **was calculated in the previous iteration**.

### **Solution 1 - value of row above calculated in the previous iteration:**

```
function copytestdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Output');
  const vs = sheet.getRange("C3:C"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const res = [[vs[0]]];
  let temp;
  for(i=1;i<vs.length;i++){
      temp = vs[i]>res[i-1] || vs[i]==1 ? vs[i] : res[i-1]-1;
      res.push([temp]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(3,4,res.length,res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

### **Solution 2 - value of row above is the original value of column C**

```
function copytestdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Output');
  const values = sheet.getRange("C3:C"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const res = [];
  values.forEach((v,i)=>{
    if(i>0){
      if(v>values[i-1] || v==1){
         res.push([v]);
      }
      else{
         res.push([values[i-1]-1]);
      }
    }
    else{
         res.push([v]);
    }
  })
  sheet.getRange(3,4,res.length,res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

**Issue with your example:**

In both cases, the example you provided does not seem to match your explanation.

Assuming your sequence is `5 5 5 5...`.

According to solution 2, the first value is 5 (because there is no value before 5), the second is 4 because the first two values are equal. But then the rest are also 4 because you have only 5s.

If we consider the first solution, then your values are 5 and 4 but then the third value is 5 because 5 is larger than 4 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your replies!

I've actually somehow managed to create a solution. I see now that my explanation may be wrong, as what I ended up doing for my desired result was to only make an IF with value on row above = 1. Not the IFs i stated in the case.

My code is probably very far from best practice, and could probably in many ways be betetr and more compressed, but it seems to be working.. So this is what I've come up with:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Output');
  sheet.getRange("B2:B").copyTo(sheet.getRange("C2:C"), {contentsOnly:true});
  sheet.getRange("C1:C1").setValue("Header");

var colc = "C";  

var rovernr = 2;
var thisnr = 3;
var lastnr = sheet.getLastRow();

var rowabove = colc+rovernr;
var thisrow = colc+thisnr;

var valueabove = sheet.getRange(rowabove).getValue();
var thisvalue = sheet.getRange(thisrow).getValue();

while (thisnr <= lastnr) {

if(valueabove == 1) {
sheet.getRange(thisrow).setValue(thisvalue);
}

else {
sheet.getRange(thisrow).setValue(valueabove-1);
}
    rovernr = rovernr+1;
    thisnr = thisnr+1;
    rowabove = colc+rovernr;
    thisrow = colc+thisnr;

  valueabove = sheet.getRange(rowabove).getValue();
  thisvalue = sheet.getRange(thisrow).getValue();

}
```

So for every iteration i "manually" on the rownumber, and fetch new cell values for the current and row above x) This is the input and output:

Input
2
2
4
4
4
4
1
3
3
3

Output
2
1
4
3
2
1
1
3
2
1